# Output not appearing in Multi-level Queue algorithm

Tags: c++, c++17, priority-queue, heap, job-scheduling

This is a multi level queue scheduling problem. I have implemented 4 levels with the system processes queue having the highest priority and the batch processes queue having the lowest priority. I have used heap for sorting the processes for priority scheduling for the system processes, round robin scheduling for interactive and interactive editing processes and first come first serve scheduling for batch processes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

// Define a struct for representing a process.
class Process {
public:
    int pid;            // Process ID
    int arrivalTime;    // Arrival time
    string type;        // Type of process (System, Interactive, etc.)
    int burstTime;      // Burst time
    int priority;       // Priority
    int curRunTime;     // Current run time

    // Default constructor
    Process() : pid(0), arrivalTime(0), type(""), burstTime(0), priority(0), curRunTime(0) {
    }

    // Parameterized constructor
    Process(int pid, int arrivalTime, string type, int burstTime, int priority)
    : pid(pid), arrivalTime(arrivalTime), type(type), burstTime(burstTime), priority(priority), curRunTime(0) {
    }

    // Getters and setters for process attributes
    int getPid() { return pid; }
    int getArrivalTime() { return arrivalTime; }
    string getType() { return type; }
    int getPriority() { return priority; }
    int getBurstTime() { return burstTime; }
    void setBurstTime(int burstTime) { this->burstTime = burstTime; }
    int getCurRunTime() { return curRunTime; }
    void setCurRunTime(int curRunTime) { this->curRunTime = curRunTime; }
};

// Define a class for a priority queue using priority.
class Priority_queue_using_priority {
private:
    vector<Process> heap; // The heap data structure
    int size;             // Current size of the queue
    int capacity;         // Maximum capacity of the queue

    // Helper functions for heap operations
    int parent(int i) { return (i - 1) / 2; }
    int leftChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 1; }
    int rightChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 2; }
    void swap(int i, int j) {
        Process temp = heap[i];
        heap[i] = heap[j];
        heap[j] = temp;
    }

public:
    // Constructor to initialize the priority queue.
    Priority_queue_using_priority(int capacity) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->size = 0;
        this->heap = vector<Process>(capacity);
    }

    // Insert a process into the priority queue based on its priority and arrival time.
    void insert(Process process) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            cout << "Heap is full, cannot insert." << endl;
            return;
        }

        size++;
        int i = size - 1;
        heap[i] = process;

        while (i != 0) {
            if (heap[parent(i)].getPriority() > heap[i].getPriority() ||
                (heap[parent(i)].getPriority() == heap[i].getPriority() &&
                 heap[parent(i)].getArrivalTime() > heap[i].getArrivalTime())) {
                swap(i, parent(i));
                i = parent(i);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Extract the process with the highest priority.
    Process extractMin() {
        if (size <= 0) {
            cout << "Heap is empty." << endl;
            return Process(0, 0, "", 0, 0);
        }

        if (size == 1) {
            size--;
            return heap[0];
        }

        Process root = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[size - 1];
        size--;
        minHeapify(0);

        return root;
    }

    // Maintain the min-heap property.
    void minHeapify(int i) {
        int left = leftChild(i);
        int right = rightChild(i);
        int smallest = i;

        if (left < size &&
            (heap[left].getPriority() < heap[i].getPriority() ||
             (heap[left].getPriority() == heap[i].getPriority() &&
              heap[left].getArrivalTime() < heap[i].getArrivalTime()))) {
            smallest = left;
        }
        if (right < size &&
            (heap[right].getPriority() < heap[smallest].getPriority() ||
             (heap[right].getPriority() == heap[smallest].getPriority() &&
              heap[right].getArrivalTime() < heap[smallest].getArrivalTime()))) {
            smallest = right;
        }

        if (smallest != i) {
            swap(i, smallest);
            minHeapify(smallest);
        }
    }

    // Get the process with the highest priority (root of the heap).
    Process top() { return heap[0]; }

    // Check if the priority queue is empty.
    bool isEmpty() { return size == 0; }
};

// Define a class for a regular priority queue.
class Priority_queue {
private:
    vector<Process> heap; // The heap data structure
    int size;             // Current size of the queue
    int capacity;         // Maximum capacity of the queue

    // Helper functions for heap operations
    int parent(int i) { return (i - 1) / 2; }
    int leftChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 1; }
    int rightChild(int i) { return 2 * i + 2; }
    void swap(int i, int j) {
        Process temp = heap[i];
        heap[i] = heap[j];
        heap[j] = temp;
    }

public:
    // Constructor to initialize the priority queue.
    Priority_queue(int capacity) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->size = 0;
        this->heap = vector<Process>(capacity);
    }

    // Insert a process into the priority queue based on its arrival time.
    void insert(Process process) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            cout << "Heap is full, cannot insert." << endl;
            return;
        }

        size++;
        int i = size - 1;
        heap[i] = process;

        while (i != 0 && heap[parent(i)].getArrivalTime() > heap[i].getArrivalTime()) {
            swap(i, parent(i));
            i = parent(i);
        }
    }

    // Extract the process with the smallest arrival time.
    Process extractMin() {
        if (size <= 0) {
            cout << "Heap is empty." << endl;
            return Process(0, 0, "", 0, 0);
        }

        if (size == 1) {
            size--;
            return heap[0];
        }

        Process root = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[size - 1];
        size--;
        minHeapify(0);

        return root;
    }

    // Maintain the min-heap property.
    void minHeapify(int i) {
        int left = leftChild(i);
        int right = rightChild(i);
        int smallest = i;

        if (left < size && heap[left].getArrivalTime() < heap[i].getArrivalTime())
            smallest = left;
        if (right < size && heap[right].getArrivalTime() < heap[smallest].getArrivalTime())
            smallest = right;

        if (smallest != i) {
            swap(i, smallest);
            minHeapify(smallest);
        }
    }

    // Get the process with the smallest arrival time (root of the heap).
    Process top() { return heap[0]; }

    // Check if the priority queue is empty.
    bool isEmpty() { return size == 0; }
};

// Define a class for a simple queue.
class Queue {
private:
    int front, rear, size;
    int capacity;
    vector<Process> queue;

public:
    // Constructor to initialize the queue.
    Queue(int capacity) {
        this->capacity = capacity;
        this->front = this->size = 0;
        this->rear = capacity - 1;
        this->queue = vector<Process>(capacity);
    }

    // Check if the queue is full.
    bool isFull() { return (size == capacity); }

    // Check if the queue is empty.
    bool isEmpty() { return (size == 0); }

    // Enqueue a process into the queue.
    void enqueue(Process process) {
        if (isFull()) {
            cout << "Queue is full. Cannot enqueue." << endl;
            return;
        }

        rear = (rear + 1) % capacity;
        queue[rear] = process;
        size++;
    }

    // Dequeue a process from the queue.
    Process dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Queue is empty. Cannot dequeue." << endl;
            return Process(0, 0, "", 0, 0);
        }

        Process process = queue[front];
        front = (front + 1) % capacity;
        size--;
        return process;
    }

    // Get the front process in the queue.
    Process Front() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Queue is empty." << endl;
            return Process(0, 0, "", 0, 0);
        }
        return queue[front];
    }

    // Simulate the execution of a process for one second.
    void runForOneSec() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Queue is empty. Cannot Run." << endl;
            return;
        }
        queue[front].setBurstTime(queue[front].getBurstTime() - 1);
        queue[front].setCurRunTime(queue[front].getCurRunTime() + 1);
    }
};

// Define a class for representing a Gantt Chart entry.
class GrantChart {
public:
    int pid;         // Process ID
    int startTime;   // Start time
    int endTime;     // End time
    GrantChart* next; // Pointer to the next entry

    // Constructor to initialize a Gantt Chart entry.
    GrantChart(int pid, int startTime, int endTime) {
        this->pid = pid;
        this->startTime = startTime;
        this->endTime = endTime;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

int currentTime;
GrantChart* chart;
vector<int> turnAroundTime;
vector<int> waitingTime;
vector<int> queueEnteringTime;

// Function to execute a process and update the Gantt Chart.
void executeProcess(Process process, int startTime, int endTime) {
    chart->next = new GrantChart(process.getPid(), startTime, endTime);
    chart = chart->next;
}

// Function to schedule processes using the Round Robin algorithm.
void RoundRobinScheduler(Queue& readyQueue) {
    int timeQuantum = 2;
    readyQueue.runForOneSec();
    Process executingProcess = readyQueue.Front();
    int idx = executingProcess.getPid() - 1;
    int remainingBurstTime = executingProcess.getBurstTime();
    waitingTime[idx] += currentTime - queueEnteringTime[idx];

    if (remainingBurstTime == 0) {
        currentTime += 1;
        executeProcess(executingProcess, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        readyQueue.dequeue();
        turnAroundTime[idx] = currentTime - executingProcess.getArrivalTime();
    }
    else if (executingProcess.getCurRunTime() == timeQuantum) {
        currentTime += 1;
        readyQueue.dequeue();
        readyQueue.enqueue(executingProcess);
        executeProcess(executingProcess, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        queueEnteringTime[idx] = currentTime;
        executingProcess.setCurRunTime(0);
    }
    else {
        currentTime += 1;
        executeProcess(executingProcess, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        queueEnteringTime[idx] = currentTime;
    }
}

// Function to schedule processes based on priority.
void priorityScheduler(Priority_queue_using_priority& readyQueue) {
    Process process = readyQueue.extractMin();
    int remainingBurstTime = process.getBurstTime();
    int idx = process.getPid() - 1;
    waitingTime[idx] += currentTime - queueEnteringTime[idx];

    if (remainingBurstTime <= 1) {
        currentTime += 1;
        executeProcess(process, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        turnAroundTime[idx] = currentTime - process.getArrivalTime();
    } else {
        currentTime += 1;
        process.setBurstTime(remainingBurstTime - 1);
        readyQueue.insert(process);
        executeProcess(process, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        queueEnteringTime[idx] = currentTime;
    }
}

// Function to schedule processes based on First-Come-First-Serve (FCFS).
void firstComeFirstServeScheduler(Priority_queue& readyQueue) {
    Process process = readyQueue.extractMin();
    int remainingBurstTime = process.getBurstTime();
    int idx = process.getPid() - 1;
    waitingTime[idx] += currentTime - queueEnteringTime[idx];

    if (remainingBurstTime <= 1) {
        currentTime += 1;
        executeProcess(process, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        turnAroundTime[idx] = currentTime - process.getArrivalTime();
    } else {
        currentTime += 1;
        process.setBurstTime(remainingBurstTime - 1);
        readyQueue.insert(process);
        executeProcess(process, currentTime - 1, currentTime);
        queueEnteringTime[idx] = currentTime;
    }
}

// Function to convert process type (integer) to a string.
string getTypeString(int type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 1:
            return "System";
        case 2:
            return "Interactive";
        case 3:
            return "Interactive Editing";
        case 4:
            return "Batch";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}

int main() {
    int numProcesses;
    cin >> numProcesses;

    Priority_queue arrivedProcesses(numProcesses);

    currentTime = 0;
    chart = new GrantChart(-1, 0, 0);
    turnAroundTime = vector<int>(numProcesses, 0);
    waitingTime = vector<int>(numProcesses, 0);
    queueEnteringTime = vector<int>(numProcesses, 0);
    GrantChart* headOfChart = chart;

    Priority_queue_using_priority systemProcesses(numProcesses);
    Queue interactiveProcesses(numProcesses);
    Queue interactiveEditingProcesses(numProcesses);
    Priority_queue batchProcess(numProcesses);

    // Read process information and add them to the arrived processes queue.
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; i++) {
        int arrivalTime, burstTime, priority, type;
        cin >> arrivalTime >> burstTime >> priority >> type;
        Process process(i + 1, arrivalTime, getTypeString(type), burstTime, priority);
        arrivedProcesses.insert(process);
        queueEnteringTime[i] = arrivalTime;
        waitingTime[i] = 0;
    }

    // Main scheduling loop.
    while (!arrivedProcesses.isEmpty() || !systemProcesses.isEmpty() || !interactiveProcesses.isEmpty() || !interactiveEditingProcesses.isEmpty() || !batchProcess.isEmpty()) {
        while (!arrivedProcesses.isEmpty() && arrivedProcesses.top().getArrivalTime() <= currentTime) {
            Process topushed = arrivedProcesses.extractMin();
            if (topushed.getType() == "System") systemProcesses.insert(topushed);
            else if (topushed.getType() == "Interactive") interactiveProcesses.enqueue(topushed);
            else if (topushed.getType() == "Interactive Editing") interactiveEditingProcesses.enqueue(topushed);
            else if (topushed.getType() == "Batch") batchProcess.insert(topushed);
        }
        if (!systemProcesses.isEmpty()) {
            priorityScheduler(systemProcesses);
        } else if (!interactiveProcesses.isEmpty()) {
            RoundRobinScheduler(interactiveProcesses);
        } else if (!interactiveEditingProcesses.isEmpty()) {
            RoundRobinScheduler(interactiveEditingProcesses);
        } else if (!batchProcess.isEmpty()) {
            firstComeFirstServeScheduler(batchProcess);
        }
        else currentTime++;
    }

    // Print the Gantt Chart.
    chart = headOfChart->next;
    cout << "GRANT CHART" << endl;
    cout << "0";
    int prev = 0;
    while (chart != nullptr) {
        if (prev != chart->startTime) {
            cout << " | IDLE | " << chart->startTime;
        }
        while (chart->next != nullptr && chart->pid == chart->next->pid) {
            chart = chart->next;
        }
        cout << " | P" << chart->pid << " | " << chart->endTime;
        prev = chart->endTime;
        chart = chart->next;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Print waiting times for each process and calculate average waiting time.
    cout << "Waiting Time For Each Process" << endl;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; i++) {
        cout << "P" << i + 1 << ": " << waitingTime[i] << endl;
        sum += waitingTime[i];
    }
    cout << "Average Waiting Time: " << sum / numProcesses << endl;

    // Print turn around times for each process and calculate average turn around time.
    cout << "Turn Around Time Of Each Process" << endl;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; i++) {
        cout << "P" << i + 1 << ": " << turnAroundTime[i] << endl;
        sum += turnAroundTime[i];
    }
    cout << "Average Turn Around Time: " << sum / numProcesses << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, when executing the program, there is no output on the screen. Can anyone help me resolve this issue and point out where i went wrong?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/n51qzW1ca). The program prints *something* for me.

Comment: Does it give the desired output?

Comment: I don't know what the output is supposed to be. Or input, for that matter. But it prints something. You can see for yourself: click the link, look at the output panel on the bottom right.